# Linq Left Join or similar

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I'm trying to fill my query with several table's info but I'm in trouble some fields are null or empty, so Im looking for a way to bring my info even if is null or empty or filled. Can you help me?? thanks!!

```
var generales = (from queja in db.RegistroQueja
join datosQueja in db.DatosQueja on queja.ID equals datosQueja.Id_Registro into g
from datosQueja in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
join estado in db.Estado on datosQueja.Estado equals estado.ID
join lugar in db.Lugar on datosQueja.Lugar equals lugar.ID
join genero in db.Genero on datosQueja.Genero equals genero.ID
join tipoUser in db.Clasificacion on datosQueja.Clasificacion equals tipoUser.ID
join calDetalle in db.CalificacionDetalle on queja.ID equals calDetalle.Id_Registro into f
from calDetalle in f.DefaultIfEmpty()
join medioC in db.Medio_Captacion on calDetalle.Medio_Captacion equals medioC.ID
join temaCorp in db.Dimension on calDetalle.Dimension equals temaCorp.ID
join tipoInc in db.Tipo_Incidencia on calDetalle.Tipo_Incidencia equals tipoInc.ID
join dataIncidencia in db.RegistroIncidencia on calDetalle.Incidencia equals dataIncidencia.Id
join incidencia in db.TemaIncidencia on dataIncidencia.TemaIncidencia equals incidencia.IDTemaIncidencia
join estatus in db.Estatus_SAC on queja.Estatus equals estatus.Id
join contexto in db.Contextualizacion on queja.ID equals contexto.Id_Registro into e
from contexto in e.DefaultIfEmpty()

join procInt0 in db.ProcesoInterno on queja.ID equals procInt0.Id_Registro into d
from procInt0 in d.DefaultIfEmpty()
join cierre in db.Cierre_Seguimiento on queja.ID equals cierre.Id_Registro into c
from cierre in c.DefaultIfEmpty()

join tipoCierre in db.Tipo_Cierre on cierre.Tipo_Cierre equals tipoCierre.Id
join paises in db.Pais on datosQueja.Pais equals paises.Id
//join regiones in db.Region on datosQueja.Estado equals regiones.Id
join sitios in db.Sitio on datosQueja.Unidad equals sitios.Id

where queja.Fecha_creacion >= fechaI && queja.Fecha_modificacion <= fechaC
select new
{
    //Campos informacion de contacto
    Folio = queja.Folio,
    CasoAnonimo = queja.Queja_Anonima,
    NombreContacto = String.IsNullOrEmpty(g.Nombre) ? "" : datosQueja.Nombre,
    TelefonoContacto = String.IsNullOrEmpty(datosQueja.Telefono) ? "" : datosQueja.Telefono,
    Telefono2 = datosQueja.Extencion,
    GeneroInt = datosQueja.Genero,
    Genero = String.IsNullOrEmpty(genero.Genero1) ? "" : genero.Genero1,
    EdadContacto = datosQueja.Edad,
    Tipo = String.IsNullOrEmpty(datosQueja.Tipo) ? "" : datosQueja.Tipo,
    CorreoContacto = String.IsNullOrEmpty(datosQueja.Correo) ? "" : datosQueja.Correo,
    TipoUsuario = datosQueja.Clasificacion,
    TipoUsuarioNombre = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tipoUser.Nombre) ? "" : tipoUser.Nombre,
    EspecificarContacto = String.IsNullOrEmpty(datosQueja.Especificar) ? "" : datosQueja.Especificar,
    // Campos ubicacion
    Pais = datosQueja.Pais,
    PaisNombre = paises.Nombre,
    Estados = datosQueja.Estado,
    EstadosNombre = estado.Nombre,
    OtroEstado = datosQueja.Estado_Otro,
    Lugar = datosQueja.Lugar,
    LugarNombre = lugar.Nombre,
    CodigoP = datosQueja.CP,
    Colonia = datosQueja.Colonia,
    Unidad = datosQueja.Unidad,
    UnidadNombre = sitios.Nombre,
    Direccion = datosQueja.Direccion,
    Especifiaciones = datosQueja.Especificaciones,
    FechaEvento = datosQueja.Fecha_Evento,
    DescripcionCaso = datosQueja.Descripcion,
    Estatus = queja.Estatus,
    EstatusNombre = estatus.Nombre,

    MedioCapacitacion = calDetalle.Medio_Captacion,
    MedioCaptacionNombre = medioC.Nombre,
    Dimension = calDetalle.Dimension,
    TemaCorporativoNombre = temaCorp.Nombre,
    TipoIncidencia = calDetalle.Tipo_Incidencia,
    TipoIncidenciaNombre = tipoInc.Nombre,
    Incidencia = calDetalle.Incidencia,
    IncidenciaNombre = incidencia.Nombre,

    FechaInicio = queja.Fecha_creacion,
    FechaFin = queja.Fecha_modificacion,
    //Contextualizacion
    WhatsApp = contexto.WhatsApp,
    Correo = contexto.Correo,
    Llamada = contexto.Llamada,
    ObservacionesContext = contexto.Observaciones,
    Confirmacion_Recibido = contexto.Confirmacion_Recibido,

    //Proceso Interno
    ValidacionExterna = procInt0.Validacion_Externa,
    JustificacionValidacion = String.IsNullOrEmpty(procInt0.Justificacion_Validacion) ? "" : procInt0.Justificacion_Validacion,
    RespaldoJuridico = procInt0.Respaldo_Juridico,
    JustificacionRespaldo = String.IsNullOrEmpty(procInt0.Justificacion_Respaldo) ? "" : procInt0.Justificacion_Respaldo,
    CierreProceso = procInt0.Cierre_Proceso,

    // Cierre 
    Tipo_Cierre = cierre.Tipo_Cierre,
    Tipo_Cierre_Nombre = tipoCierre.Nombre,
    Observaciones = cierre.Observaciones,
    Testimonio = cierre.Testimonio,
    Expediente_Respaldo = cierre.Expediente_Respaldo,
    Oficio_Tercero = cierre.Oficio_Tercero,
    Bitacoras_Comunitarias = cierre.Bitacoras_Comunitarias,
    Memoria_Inicial = cierre.Memoria_Inicial,
    Memoria_Final = cierre.Memoria_Final,
    Recibo_Deducible = cierre.Recibo_Deducible,
    Oficio_Agradecimiento = cierre.Oficio_Agradecimiento,
    Resultados_Estudios = cierre.Resultados_Estudios,
    Correo_Seguimiento = cierre.Correo_Seguimiento,
    Comunicados_Oficiales = cierre.Comunicados_Oficiales,
    Notas_Periodisticas = cierre.Notas_Periodisticas,
    Respaldo_Redes = cierre.Respaldo_Redes,
    Otros = cierre.Otros,
    Comunicacion = cierre.Comunicacion,
    Dialogo_Directo = cierre.Dialogo_Directo,
    Comunicacion_Clave = cierre.Comunicacion_Clave,
    Difusion_Redes = cierre.Difusion_Redes,
    Cierre_Desarrollo = cierre.Cierre_Desarrollo,
    Cierre_SAC = cierre.Cierre_SAC,

}).Distinct().ToList().Select(p => new DataGeneral
{
    Folio = p.Folio,
    CasoAnonimo = p.CasoAnonimo,
    NombreContacto = p.NombreContacto,
    TelefonoContacto = p.TelefonoContacto,
    Telefono2 = p.Telefono2,
    GeneroInt = p.GeneroInt,
    Genero = p.Genero,
    EdadContacto = p.EdadContacto,
    Tipo = p.Tipo,
    CorreoContacto = p.CorreoContacto,
    TipoUsuario = p.TipoUsuario,
    TipoUsuarioNombre = p.TipoUsuarioNombre,
    EspecificarContacto = p.EspecificarContacto,
    //Campos ubicacion
    Pais = p.Pais,
    PaisNombre = p.PaisNombre,
    Estado = p.Estados,
    EstadosNombre = p.EstadosNombre,
    OtroEstado = p.OtroEstado,
    Lugar = p.Lugar,
    LugarNombre = p.LugarNombre,
    CodigoP = p.CodigoP,
    Colonia = p.Colonia,
    Unidad = p.Unidad,
    UnidadNombre = p.UnidadNombre,
    Direccion = p.Direccion,
    Especifiaciones = p.Especifiaciones,
    FechaEvento = p.FechaEvento,
    DescripcionCaso = p.DescripcionCaso,
    MedioCapacitacion = p.MedioCapacitacion,
    MedioCaptacionNombre = p.MedioCaptacionNombre,
    TemaCorporativo = p.Dimension,
    TemaCorporativoNombre = p.TemaCorporativoNombre,
    TipoIncidencia = p.TipoIncidencia,
    TipoIncidenciaNombre = p.TipoIncidenciaNombre,
    Incidencia = p.Incidencia,
    IncidenciaNombre = p.IncidenciaNombre,
    Estatus = p.Estatus,
    EstatusNombre = p.EstatusNombre,
    FechaInicio = p.FechaInicio,
    FechaFin = p.FechaFin,
    //Context
    WhatsApp = p.WhatsApp,
    Correo = p.Correo,
    Llamada = p.Llamada,
    ObservacionesContext = p.ObservacionesContext,
    Confirmacion_Recibido = p.Confirmacion_Recibido,
    //proceso Intern
    ValidacionExterna = p.ValidacionExterna,
    JustificacionValidacion = p.JustificacionValidacion,
    JustificacionRespaldo = p.JustificacionRespaldo,
    RespaldoJuridico = p.RespaldoJuridico,
    CierreProceso = p.CierreProceso,

    ////  cierre 
    Tipo_Cierre = p.Tipo_Cierre,
    Tipo_CierreNombre = p.Tipo_Cierre_Nombre,
    Observaciones = p.Observaciones,
    Testimonio = p.Testimonio,
    Expediente_Respaldo = p.Expediente_Respaldo,
    Oficio_Tercero = p.Oficio_Tercero,
    Bitacoras_Comunitarias = p.Bitacoras_Comunitarias,
    Memoria_Inicial = p.Memoria_Inicial,
    Memoria_Final = p.Memoria_Final,
    Recibo_Deducible = p.Recibo_Deducible,
    Oficio_Agradecimiento = p.Oficio_Agradecimiento,
    Resultados_Estudios = p.Resultados_Estudios,
    Correo_Seguimiento = p.Correo_Seguimiento,
    Comunicados_Oficiales = p.Comunicados_Oficiales,
    Notas_Periodisticas = p.Notas_Periodisticas,
    Respaldo_Redes = p.Respaldo_Redes,
    Otros = p.Otros,
    Comunicacion = p.Comunicacion,
    Dialogo_Directo = p.Dialogo_Directo,
    Comunicacion_Clave = p.Comunicacion_Clave,
    Difusion_Redes = p.Difusion_Redes,
    Cierre_Desarrollo = p.Cierre_Desarrollo,
    Cierre_SAC = p.Cierre_SAC,
}).DefaultIfEmpty();
```

Comment: Please format your code properly , that will help someone to easily understatnd your code and fix the issue.

Comment: If any of these joins are based on FK relationships then you should have navigation properties and I'd suggest looking into using them instead as it's often much easier to srite queries using them vs a ton of joins.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you provide more details about how the null or empty fields are causing you problems? You have `DefaultIfEmpty` so those are left joins that handle null/empty fields when joining. Also,are you using LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

I m using this code in my projects

```
    public IQueryable<AgcTaskType> GetByAgcOfficerId(Guid id)
    {
        return from entity in GetQueryable()
               join companyX in _context.Companies on entity.CompanyId equals companyX.Id into companyJoin
               from company in companyJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join cwrX in _context.CompanyWorkingRegions.GetByAgcOfficer(id) on company.Id equals cwrX.CompanyId into cwrJoin
               from cwr in cwrJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where !entity.CompanyId.HasValue || (entity.CompanyId.HasValue &&  cwr != null)
               select entity;
    }
```

In this example, this part of code

```
           join companyX in _context.Companies on entity.CompanyId equals companyX.Id into companyJoin
           from company in companyJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

is should work for you.

You already use it in your code, just check your algorithm.